# VueJs - Animate number changes

Tags: javascript, animation, vue.js

I'm looking to animate number changes using VueJs.

For example I have:

```
{{ number }}
```

Then `number` changes from `0` to `100`, I would like the element to count up to `100` rather than just jumping stright to it.

How would I do this without using any 3rd party (pure Js/VueJs) excluding VueJs?

Comment: Started to answer it but I'm headed out for the night.  Here's what I was working on: https://jsfiddle.net/5nobcLq0/1/ Basically, the idea is to keep the number separate from the displayed number, and if they are different increment the display number towards the real number.  I think ideally this would be a component of its own, or a directive like `v-animate`. I'll look at it more tomorrow

Comment: I had a look at v-animate but couldn't find anything that would help me

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Got this working as a custom component: https://jsfiddle.net/5nobcLq0/5/

**html**

```
<body>
  <input v-model="number">
  <animated-number :number="number"></animated-number>
</body>
```

**js**

```
Vue.component('animated-number', {

  template:"{{ displayNumber }}",
  props: {'number': { default:0 }},

  data () {
    return {
      displayNumber:0,
      interval:false
    }
  },

  ready () {
    this.displayNumber = this.number ? this.number : 0;
  },

  watch: {
    number () {
      clearInterval(this.interval);

      if(this.number == this.displayNumber) {
        return;
      }

      this.interval = window.setInterval(() => {
        if(this.displayNumber != this.number) {
          var change = (this.number - this.displayNumber) / 10;
          change = change >= 0 ? Math.ceil(change) : Math.floor(change);
          this.displayNumber = this.displayNumber + change;
        }
      }, 20);
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el:'body',
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: would you be able to adjust this to support decimals? Currently if the number isn't whole it flickers and jumps up and down

Comment: the line `change = change >= 0 ? Math.ceil(change) : Math.floor(change);` uses `Math.floor` and `Math.ceil` to round the change off.  Just remove that line and it should work.  You may want to round to a certain number of decimals instead.

Comment: I'd suggest using requestAnimationFrame() instead of setInterval()

Comment: You may want to change `ready()` to `mounted()` for Vue2 and Vue3. Other than that it works great

Answer (score 14):

I realize this is an older post, but I was looking for something similar and I found an example straight from the vue.js 2.0 documentation. You can find it here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitioning-state.html#Organizing-Transitions-into-Components

I've recreated it in the snippet below.

```js
// This complex tweening logic can now be reused between
// any integers we may wish to animate in our application.
// Components also offer a clean interface for configuring
// more dynamic transitions and complex transition
// strategies.
Vue.component('animated-integer', {
  template: '<span>{{ tweeningValue }}</span>',
  props: {
    value: {
      type: Number,
      required: true
    }
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      tweeningValue: 0
    }
  },
  watch: {
    value: function(newValue, oldValue) {
      this.tween(oldValue, newValue)
    }
  },
  mounted: function() {
    this.tween(0, this.value)
  },
  methods: {
    tween: function(startValue, endValue) {
      var vm = this

      function animate() {
        if (TWEEN.update()) {
          requestAnimationFrame(animate)
        }
      }
      new TWEEN.Tween({
          tweeningValue: startValue
        })
        .to({
          tweeningValue: endValue
        }, 500)
        .onUpdate(function() {
          vm.tweeningValue = this.tweeningValue.toFixed(0)
        })
        .start()
      animate()
    }
  }
})
// All complexity has now been removed from the main Vue instance!
new Vue({
  el: '#example-8',
  data: {
    firstNumber: 20,
    secondNumber: 40
  },
  computed: {
    result: function() {
      return this.firstNumber + this.secondNumber
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.4.3/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tween.js"></script>
<div id="example-8">
  <input v-model.number="firstNumber" type="number" step="20"> +
  <input v-model.number="secondNumber" type="number" step="20"> = {{ result }}
  <p>
    <animated-integer v-bind:value="firstNumber"></animated-integer> +
    <animated-integer v-bind:value="secondNumber"></animated-integer> =
    <animated-integer v-bind:value="result"></animated-integer>
  </p>
</div>
```

I hope that helps!
Tim

Comment: You might want to consider using this.$nextTick rather than requestAnimationFrame, since it is integrated into the VueJs dom update process.

Comment: Hi @BenjaminEllis, I just copied the example from the vue.js 2.x docs. So maybe there's a reason for using requestAnimationFrame, otherwise I would assume they would have used it in the example?

Answer (score 3):

## If you use GSAP

I took Jeff's answer and simplified it using GSAP.

```
import gsap from 'gsap';

Vue.component('animate-integer', {
  template: '<span>{{displayValue}}</span>',
  props: { value: { default: 0 } },

  data() {
    return {
      displayValue: this.value,
      tweenValue: this.value
    };
  },

  watch: {
    value() {
      gsap.to(this, {
        tweenValue: this.value,
        onUpdate: () => {
          this.displayValue = Math.ceil(this.tweenValue);
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Usage:

```
<input v-model="value">
<animate-integer :value="value"></animated-integer>
```

### Update

As I've used this component it evolved to accept duration and formatting, [here is a gist](https://gist.github.com/millerrafi/65fc1193d98ae9fcef257ab558bc3f2c).

Comment: How about without the input and if we wanna animate after page load?

Comment: @OutForCode The input isn't necessary, I put it there as an example. Pass in any value you want, `
<animate-integer :value="someValue"></animated-integer>`, and anytime that value changes, the component animates. If that is more clear I'll update the answer.

Comment: I can get it. But I am looking for a load time animate. Value is not going to change once the page is loaded or into view, it should animate from 0 to the value. Can you please help me with that?

Comment: You can do something like :value="inView ? myValue : 0". inView is false until you are ready to animate, then set it to true.

Answer (score 1):

If you want support for the animation of floating-point numbers and negative numbers also this vue component will work. It's built on top of [@jeff's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3720222/jeff) answer. Change the number 5 or make it a prop to control how fast or slow the animation happens.

```
<template>
  <span>{{displayNumber}}</span>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      displayNumber: 0,
      counter: false
    };
  },
  props: {
    number: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0
    }
  },
  watch: {
    number () {
      clearInterval(this.counter);
      if (this.number === this.displayNumber) {
        return;
      }
      this.counter = setInterval(function () {
        if (Math.floor(this.displayNumber) !== Math.floor(this.number)) {
          var change = (this.number - this.displayNumber) / 5;
          change = change >= 0 ? Math.ceil(change) : Math.floor(change);
          this.displayNumber = this.displayNumber + change;
        } else {
          this.displayNumber = this.number;
          clearInterval(this.counter);
        }
      }.bind(this), 20);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a vue 3 composition API component, based on [@jeff's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3720222/jeff) & [@AnandShiva's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5131139/anandshiva) answers. Here it is:

```
<template>{{ displayNumber }}</template>

<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
  value: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0,
  },
  speed: {
    // smaller is faster
    type: Number,
    default: 5,
  },
});

const displayNumber = ref(props.value);
let interval = null;

watch(
  () => props.value,
  (newVal) => {
    clearInterval(interval);

    if (newVal === displayNumber.value) {
      return;
    }

    interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (Math.floor(displayNumber.value) !== Math.floor(newVal)) {
        var change = (newVal - displayNumber.value) / props.speed;
        change = change >= 0 ? Math.ceil(change) : Math.floor(change);
        displayNumber.value = displayNumber.value + change;
      } else {
        displayNumber.value = newVal;
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
    }, 20);
  }
);
</script>
```